# SQL Statement - Where Clause depending on input

Tags: sql

I am trying to write an sql statement where the "where" clause is dependent on whether or not values are null or not

I have the values rows Name and Number. I want to search for everything in a table where is Name IS NULL then Number = "X". I want another case where if Number is NULL then search for where Name = "X". And a last case WHERE if both are NOT NULL then search for where Name = "X" and Room = "X"

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE
CASE
    WHEN a.Name IS NULL AND b.Number IS NOT NULL THEN a.Name = "X"
    ....
END;
```

The ... would be the other 2 cases. I am however told that I cannot use cases for this example, how else would I be able to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would translate your requirement with `or`ed conditions:

```
where
    -- Name IS NULL then Number = "X"
    (name is null and number = 'X')

    --  if Number is NULL then search for where Name = "X"
    or (number is null and name = 'X')

    -- WHERE if both are NOT NULL then search for where Name = "X" and Room = "X"
    or (name = 'X' and number is not null and room = 'X')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no sample data to test on, but this query should yield you the results you  are looking for.

What you need to do is employ a little bit of [Boolean Logic](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwji5NbMzOLlAhUmnOAKHQXjDsUQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3resource.com%2Fsql%2Fboolean-operator%2Fsql-boolean-operators.php&usg=AOvVaw0Off9eXm4Gnp2SxruoXqnt), essentially what you need to say is: "If one of these conditions is true, then return the result"
, where the condition are the sets of rules you outline above.

The SQL `OR` statement provides that opportunity. The query below translates your written requests into `OR` statements, so the query will select everything from A and B assuming that one of those conditions in the `WHERE` statement is met.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    A 
        INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE
    (name IS NULL AND number = "X")
    OR 
    (number IS NULL AND name = "X")
    OR 
    (name = "X" AND number IS NOT NULL AND room = "X")
```